# Eclipse maven not adding dependencies

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies

I am new to maven and am experiencing difficulties while trying to mavenise a Java project.

**Setting:**
IDE: Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
Java: 8
m2e: 1.8.2

**What I did:**
- copy-pasted the entire original java project and renamed it
- right-click in eclipse: Configure > Convert to Maven project
- in java build path, deletion of libraries import from original local lib repo. The build path shows the `Maven Dependencies` folder, with the only junit library.
- `maven install` => downloaded things in the user/.m2/repository/, but not all.

**What does not work:**
When I try to add a dependency right from a file:

[image: dependency right from a file],

nothing pops up in the artifact selection windows, even though there is a `commons-logging/` folder in `m2/repository`

[image: search not working]

When I try to add the dependency manually in the `pom.xml`:
    
    `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.kie.modules</groupId>
      <artifactId>org-apache-commons-configuration-main</artifactId>
      <version>6.5.0.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>`

but the package resolution error still appears in the java file, and I get this warning after `Maven install`

```
`[WARNING] The POM for org.kie.modules:org-apache-commons-configuration-main:pom:6.5.0.Final is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details`
```

I did `Maven Update project`, eclipse `project clean`, nothing changes.

My goal for now is just that eclipse understands (at least for one library), that it has to take it from maven repository. I still have many other dependencies to solve (intra-project), but that will be the next step.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the issue is stated in the warning message :

> [WARNING] **The POM for
>   org.kie.modules:org-apache-commons-configuration-main:pom:6.5.0.Final
>   is invalid**, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available,
>   enable debug logging for more details

It means that the pom.xml downloaded in your local maven repository exists but is not valid.
Delete the folder of the dependency downloaded in your local maven repository and try again.
If you still have the same problem, check that **your** central repository that provides the dependency provides also correctly the `pom.xml` for that.
You can do it by browsing the directory of the dependency from a web browser.
For example we can see that the maven central repository provides a valid pom :
 [http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/kie/modules/org-apache-commons-collections-main/6.5.0.Final/org-apache-commons-collections-main-6.5.0.Final.pom](http://%20http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/kie/modules/org-apache-commons-collections-main/6.5.0.Final/org-apache-commons-collections-main-6.5.0.Final.pom)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the pb remains:

I removed my `~/.m2/repository` and executed again `mvn clean install`.  Thereafter I do have the dependency in `~/.m2/repository/org/kie/...` with the correct [POM](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.kie.modules%7Corg-apache-commons-configuration-main%7C6.5.0.Final%7Cpom), but now get `[ERROR] /myproject/src/main/java/configuration/MyClass.java:  package org.apache.commons.configuration does not exist`. Also, the folder `src/main/resources` remains empty.

Comment: I think understanding the cause of the problem But before can you answer to this question ? Why did you include a dependency from `org.kie.modules`. Do you use Drools or JBPM ?

Comment: good question (!) I simply searched the name of the import (`org.apache.commons.configuration`) in the Central Repo, got the `kie`, and didn't question further.... I now realized that this [POM](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccommons-configuration%7Ccommons-configuration%7C1.10%7Cjar) is the one.
I changed my pom, deleted the local repo and did a new `mvn clean install`. Result: the lib is taken into account !
Remain the last question: why eclipse does not show any result upon searching for a artifact? (cf screenshot). Thanks again.